# создание нового формата assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Можно ли  на assembler создавать новый форматы файлов(расширение файлов). Если да то какие книги есть по этому вопросу ?

Comment: что значит _создавать новый форматы файлов_?

Comment: Кто ж мешает-то? Только не нужно это...

Comment: нет никакой разницы какая то хитрая структура у вас в оперативной памяти или в файле. вы можете сохранить в файл любую структуру. и я сильно сомневаюсь, что есть какие то книги специально по этому вопросу. для создания любых структур достаточно здравого смысла и знания общих тем программирования, таких как типы данных

Answer (score 3):

Расширение файла - это фикция.

На самом деле есть полное имя файла, которое во времена голого ДОСа делили на две части - просто имя и расширение,- и между ними ставили точку. Т.е. точка отсутствовала в записи элемента каталога и добавлялась ДОСом.

В настоящее время, время "длинных" имён, точка является полноправным символом имени. А расширением считается часть полного имени файла после последней точки, если в имени есть хотя бы одна точка, или отсутствующим, если точек нет.

Нет никакой жёсткой привязки расширения к типу/содержимому файла. Исполняемый файл может "иметь расширение" .TXT, или файл базы данных "расширение" .DLL - никакой особенной разницы. Просто операционная система не лезет в содержимое файла, предполагая, что расширение ему соответствует, и при неявном запросе на "исполнение" в зависимости от расширения предпринимает те или иные действия (запускает файл .EXE на выполнение, устанавливает в систему .INF, запускает Word и передаёт ему файл для .DOCX и т.п.). Ну а если содержимое не соответствует расширению, получается соответствующая ошибка.

Так что можешь придумать любое расширение и использовать его - никто не против. Только постарайся не конфликтовать с уже имеющимися, для которых у операционной системы существует сцепка расширение-действие. Основной проблемой для тебя будет не создать файл с расширением .MySuperPuperExtension, а объяснить операционке, что с этой фигнёй делать. Но это совсем другая история...

Comment: `объяснить операционке` — точнее всему, что открывает файлы в «родных» программах через библиотеку `shell32.dll` (к таким относится и проводник, который `explorer.exe`). Тем же, кто работает через низкоуровневые функции чтения-записи (например, `CreateFile()`), ничего объяснять не надо, ибо плевали они на файловые ассоциации с высокой ёлки.